# Multi-nic card switches ports on reboot

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I have a 2-port Intel NIC in my Ubuntu 18 machine, along with a NIC on the motherboard I don't use.  I originally wanted to set up two NICs with different IPs, but that failed and now I have 2 IPs on the same NIC port, but on two interfaces (eth0 and p4p1).  Often when I reboot the machine, Ubuntu will switch to the other ethernet port on the NIC (unconnected) and I can't figure out where I've gone wrong in my config.  Has anyone seen this and fixed it?  Ultimately I'd like to separate the two IPs and have each on its own ethernet port.  I just can't figure out how to assign the software interface to the hardware port. 
 I'll make logs and configs available, just tell me what you need.  Thanks.

```
# lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: p4p1
       version: 06
       serial: 10:bf:48:40:ba:c3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.0.120 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:35 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fd004000-fd004fff memory:fd000000-fd003fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82571EB/82571GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller D0/D1 (copper applications)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 00:15:17:ba:ee:72
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=5.11-2 ip=192.168.0.150 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 memory:fe9a0000-fe9bffff memory:fe980000-fe99ffff ioport:d020(size=32) memory:fe960000-fe97ffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82571EB/82571GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller D0/D1 (copper applications)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       logical name: eth1
       version: 06
       serial: 00:15:17:ba:ee:73
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=5.11-2 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:38 memory:fe940000-fe95ffff memory:fe920000-fe93ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:fe900000-fe91ffff




# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet static
  address 192.168.0.120
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  network 192.168.0.0
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.170  192.168.0.171

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.150
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  network 192.168.0.0
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.170  192.168.0.171

iface eth1 inet manual
#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet static
#  address 192.168.0.151
#  netmask 255.255.255.0
#  gateway 192.168.0.1
#  network 192.168.0.0
#  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.170  192.168.0.171




No yaml files.
```

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema :  I've tried a few more things since posting, and have IPs assigned to different interfaces, but it's still seems to switch between NICs, although now I think it's switching between the two connections due to which comes up first (no default).  How do I post the info you requested?  This is a server system, no desktop.

Comment: Open `terminal`. Execute the 3 commands. Copy the output to the clipboard. Edit your question. Paste the clipboard. Select the pasted text. Click the `{}` icon to make it human-readable.

Comment: @heynnema: added.

Comment: See my initial /etc/network/interfaces edits. I added hwaddress. Report back. Also, if you use the two ports eth0 and eth1, does the same problem occur? See `man interfaces` for more help.

Comment: You might also try adding the metric parameter to define the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet static
  hwaddress 10:bf:48:40:ba:c3
  metric 100
  address 192.168.0.120
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  network 192.168.0.0
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.170  192.168.0.171

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  hwaddress 00:15:17:ba:ee:72
  metric 200
  address 192.168.0.150
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  network 192.168.0.0
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.170  192.168.0.171

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  hwaddress 00:15:17:ba:ee:73
  metric 300
  address 192.168.0.151
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  network 192.168.0.0
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.170  192.168.0.171
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have worked once I added the ifmetric package and reset the route metrics.  Now I need to figure out how to make that permanent.

Comment: @Gordon Good news! Thanks for the update. Rather than using the ifmetric package, I think you could have just added the `metric` parameter that I mentioned earlier. Add it to each ethernet interface's stanza. See the edits in my answer.